# jQuery Mobile Not Applying Styles Only On Even Numbered Paged Visits. Also, Ajax Calls Increasing Per Visit

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Alright, admittedly there are a lot of words here, but this is a problem I've never seen before, and quite a peculiar one at that.  So, it will probably be worth the read.

I have a page that dynamically produces Listviews in response to a link clicked from $.mobile.autocomplete.
The listview has two types of `<li>'s`, and are themed accordingly and have a class set or not set accordingly.
Lets call them l-1 and l-2.

When I click on *l-1*, what should happen is that that listitem toggles a class that gives the appearance of the item being selected, similar to $.ui.selected - and only one selected item is allowed per list.
This is accomplished easily using basic jQuery.

What also should happen when I click *l-1*, is that an ajax call is made sending particular values to the server, and a callback function that highlights footer text green for success and red if there is an error.

What should happen when I click *l-2*, is that the list is replaced by another list that is the next level down on this particular hierarchy.

A little tricky to implement, but nothing that wasn't straightforward once I figured it out.  And it works .... sort of.

This is the weird thing.  If I go to the page once, select an item and then go through the steps above, everything works as expected. 
 (We're just going to look at *l-1* here).  I can generate a listview through autocomplete as many times as I like, click *l-1*, the style is applied, the ajax fires successfully, the element is highlighted, voila!  I'm happy, and pat myself on the back encouragingly.

***However***, and this is where the weirdness begins - Let's say that I leave the page by going back to the home page (not using the back-button, but just a straightforward jQuery Mobile link), and then once there, I click on the link to bring me back to this page, I'm brought back. Let's say that this page is called *Page-2*.  On *Page-2* things start off well:  I generate the list using autocomplete, but when I click on an *l-1* item, the following happens (or doesn't):

1. The style **is not** applied to the listitem.
2. The ajax request is called, and returns success.
3. The success element is highlighted.
4. Strangely the ajax is called **twice** and returns the same data.

If I leave and come back again, the same thing happens, **except**,

1. The style **is** applied to listitem.
2. The ajax call is now made **three** times.

This pattern continues (presumably for awhile - I tried up to 8 times) in the following manner:

1. On odd #'d trips back, the style **is** applied, e.g. (the 3rd trip back,5th,7th)
2. One even #'d trips back, the style **is not** applied. e.g (4th,6th,8th)
3. Each trip back, the number of ajax requests made increases by one.  See the photos of the network panel on the first trip, and on the 8th trip (this is generated by nothing other than the same mouse click).

### 1st Visit, 1 Click

[image]

### 8th Page Vist, 1 Click

[image]

You can open the images in a new tab full size by right clicking on them and selecting open in a new tab.

Any Insight?

**UPDATE**: 9/27/2012, 1:05 PM EST.

I *fixed* the issue where the styling wouldn't be applied to the clicked button on even numbered page visits, though I can't help but feel that the fix as it is is only a fix, because of the underlying problem.  Perhaps the fact that my solution fixed it will better illumniate the issue.

The solution was to move the styling of the button from before the ajax call, to the callback, so the styling isn't applied until after the ajax **requests** complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright - well, I guess this was too long for anyone to take the time to read it.  I figured out a solution, though I think the solution does not get at the heart of the problem.  The solution was to add $.fn.event.stopPropagation directly after the repeating ajax was called.

Why this should help is a clue into the problem.  The only thing I can think of that would produce this problem, and have my solution fix it is that somehow each time pageInit is called (the result was the same no matter where I  bound it, i.e. I tried pageLoad, pageShow, etc.) the function was getting cloned and attached to the end of the ever growing function which stayed bound to pageInit.

Of course that makes no sense, and I've never had that happen elsewhere, so I am at a loss, but, for now, no matter, it is fixed with no obvious detrimental effects noticed as of yet.